# What is the right way in Java to check a string for the symbol ®?

Tags: java, string, character, substring, special-characters

I want to check if a string contains the restricted symbol (®).  As of now, I'm doing it like this:

```
if(mystr.contains("®"))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This seems to work, but I really don't think using the restricted symbol in actual code is the best approach here.  What is an alternative way to check if a string contains the restricted symbol?

Comment: What about looking up the Unicode value and then use `\u` and then the number (no space in between)?

Comment: yeah I agree. you want a generic solution. this might work on one machine not another

Comment: What's wrong with using ® in the string literal?  Java has supported UTF-8 source files for years.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I feel that using a character that is not on my keyboard is a bad idea, regardless of whether or not it will actually cause any issues.  Seeing the little restricted symbol in the code would cause me some confusion if I didn't know what was going on, especially since in the code it's often too small to tell what it really is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the right encoding there shouldn't be a problem with your code. But you can also escape it to avoid issues due to the encoding used by the editor:

```
if(mystr.contains("\u00AE"))
```

During the lexical translation phase, the compiler will translate to the Unicode character.

See also [Why does Java permit escaped unicode characters in the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448180/why-does-java-permit-escaped-unicode-characters-in-the-source-code)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, I'll accept in 4 minutes!  (also, it's 00AE ;) )