# Code inside comment executed after Unicode sequence

Tags: java, comments

I have this code:

```
class ABCD
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i = 3;
        // \u000A i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Ouput:

> 4

Does this mean that Java also executes comments?

Comment: The line break represented by \u000A terminates the line comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448180/why-does-java-permit-escaped-unicode-characters-in-the-source-code

Answer (score 2):

The `i++` is on a separate line from the one-line comment. Unicode code point '\u000A' is a line-feed character.