# Which declarations are valid?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, ide, scjp

Select the three correct answers (valid declarations).

(a) `char a = '\u0061';`

(b) `char 'a' = 'a';`

(c) `char \u0061 = 'a';`

(d) `ch\u0061r a = 'a';`

(e) `ch'a'r a = 'a';`

**Answer**: (a), (c) and (d)

**Book:**

> A Programmer's Guide to Java SCJP Certification (Third Edition)

Can someone please explain the reason for the option (c) and (d) as the IDE (*IntelliJ IDEA*) is showing it in red saying:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'u0063'

[image: As shown in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Java allows unicode characters in source code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448180/why-does-java-permit-escaped-unicode-characters-in-the-source-code

Comment: Why are (c) and (d) not working for you? What error do you get?

Comment: Java converts the `\u0061` to the character `a`, that makes (c) valid. Since it is allowed and possible as a variable name, it is also allowed and possible in a type name, so `ch\u0061r` is just `char`, which makes (d) valid as well.

Comment: "not working for me" is not very helpful (e.g. do *you* convert Unicode sequences?) If using a (standard) Java compiler this must work, is one of the first operations a compiler has to do. See: [Java Language Specification 3.3. Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)

Comment: I was wrong in saying "not working for me" as I did not compile as the IDE was showing is a 'Cannot resolve symbol'. But it works once compiled. The issue was just that it is not yet supported in IDE. Thanks

Comment: not true, IDE is not showing that... at  least not mine, also works fine with `javac` compiler... maybe some settings or so, but no idea WHICH IDE your are using.

Comment: @Carlos - I have updated the IDE name and also attached a screenshot of the code in the question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Perfect! I don't use IntelliJ, but it must have an option to set encoding, but I do not think that this would help. Maybe some InteliJ users can help, despite it really seems like an bug, eventually search/raise an issue at [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: It is a known error (15 years!): [IDEABKL-89](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-89) and [IDEA-65898](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65898)

Comment: I wonder this is still not corrected... there are plenty duplicates for that ticket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can recognise Unicode escapes and translate them to UTF-16. `ch\u0061r` will become `char` which is a valid primitive type. It makes option D correct.

> ### [3.3. Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)
>
> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code unit (§3.1) for the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other characters unchanged.

`\u0061` will be translated to `a` which is a valid Java letter that can be used to form an identifier. It makes option C correct.

> ### [3.8. Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)
>
> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> ```
> Identifier:
>     IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
> IdentifierChars:
>     JavaLetter {JavaLetterOrDigit}
> JavaLetter:
>     any Unicode character that is a "Java letter"
> JavaLetterOrDigit:
>     any Unicode character that is a "Java letter-or-digit"
> ```
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns `true`.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)` returns `true`.
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (`\u0041-\u005a`), and a-z (`\u0061-\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`) and underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`). The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems. The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`\u0061` means `a`. You can use `\u0061` instead of `a`, therefore:

```
char \u0061 = 'a';
```

is the same as

```
char a = 'a';
```

and

```
ch\u0061r a = 'a';
```

is the same as

```
char a = 'a';
```