# Java Error: <Identifier> expected Public Class

Tags: java, class, methods, syntax, public

I've just started learning Java, when trying to compile the below source code using "Javac" I am getting the following error:

"C:\Java>javac 99Bottles.java

99Bottles.java:1: error:  expected

public class 99Bottles { //open Class "99Bottles"

Can't seem to figure out if this is a syntax error or if i'm missing something? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
 public class 99Bottles { //open Class "99Bottles"
    public static void main (String[] args) { //Open main method
        int Beernum = 99; //delcate intergar called "Beernum" with value of 99
        String word = "bottles"; //delcare the string "word" with a value of "bottles"

        System.out.println(Beernum + " " + word + "of beer on the walL");  //prints
        System.out.println(Beernum + " " + word + "of beer"); //prints
        System.out.println("you take one down"); //prints
        System.out.println("you pass it around"); //prints

        Beernum = Beernum - 1; //subtract 1 from the value of "Beernum"

        if (Beernum > 0) { //Check if Beernum is greater than 0
                System.out.println(Beernum + " " + "of beer on the wall"); //prints
        } else { //if the if statement is not true run this
                System.out.println("no more bottles of beer on the wall"); //prints
            }        

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think class-names cannot start with digits. Try simply changing `class 99Bottles` to `class Bottles`

Comment: Class names cannot start with a number

Comment: especially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319629/1531124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

Class name is an identifier.