# expected '{' when braces are matching correctly

Tags: java

Hi I am (**very**) new to java and I come from a c++ background
and I am getting this error:

```
Array-Lists-In-java.java:3: error: '{' expected
public class Array-Lists-In-java{
                  ^
```

and here is my code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class Array-Lists-In-java {
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ArrayList<String> grocery = {"Onions","Carrots","Olives", "olive oil"};
            
            printArray(grocery);
            
            grocery.add("Tomatoes");
            
            printArray(grocery);
            
        }
        
        public static void printArray(ArrayList<String> list)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        
    }
```

what am I doing wrong??pls correct me where i am going wrong it would be really helpful

thanks

Comment: rename Array-Lists-In-java to ArrayListsInJava and take a look at the naming conventions for java classes

Comment: Hyphens aren't valid characters for class names or variable names. stack post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475/valid-characters-in-a-java-class-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid characters in a Java class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475/valid-characters-in-a-java-class-name)

Comment: I'd expect this to be invalid in C++ too, mind you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey python_is_good_cpp_is_best! I think you are missing or have an extra flower bracket somewhere, remember each flower bracket should have a buddy! Try counting how many open flower brackets you have, and how many closed flower brackets you have. if they are the same amount, remember to use proper naming convention, programming languages dont support names having '-' cause they think you want to do subtraction, you have a '-' in your class name, try replacing '-' with underscores '_' it should work properly! thankyou!

Comment: Thank you, i will immediately change the naming.Thank you :)