# JSON Response to Java

Tags: java, json, api

I have this JSON response that I want to get converted into java.

`{"id":"4T4446Pj","count":4,"feasible":true,"route":{"0":{"name":"The Hague, The Netherlands","arrival":0,"distance":0},"1":{"name":"The Hague, The Netherlands","arrival":5,"distance":3.9},"2":{"name":"Uden, The Netherlands","arrival":93,"distance":137.1},"3":{"name":"Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands","arrival":112,"distance":160.5}}}`

I've tried online converters, but they always result in different classes, where one of the classes has distinct attributes for (0,1,2,3).

```
public class Application {
  private String id;
  private float count;
  private boolean feasible;
  Route RouteObject;

 // Getter Methods 
 // Setter Methods 
}

public class Route {
  0 0Object;
  1 1Object;
  2 2Object;
  3 3Object;

 // Getter Methods 
 // Setter Methods 
}

public class 1 {
  private String name;
  private float arrival;
  private float distance;
 // Getter Methods 
 // Setter Methods 
}
public class 0 {
  private String name;
  private float arrival;
  private float distance;
 // Getter Methods 
 // Setter Methods 
} //the same for class 2 and 3
```

The number of locations is not fixed, so I want the locations to be an array or ArrayList. How can I do that?

Comment: Class names cannot start with a number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475/valid-characters-in-a-java-class-name

Comment: And that means that you are going to have to 1) design / implement the Java classes by hand and 2) write a custom mapper.

Comment: @StephenC Or just use a `Map<String, Route>`.

Comment: Yea ... maybe ... but the point is that an automatic JSON -> Java class generator won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you understand the [difference between classes and objects](https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-object-and-class).
In order to use the JSON in your Java code you have to

1. Create Java classes which mimic the JSON structure
2. Use a JSON parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to create your Java object instances from JSON. This is also called "deserialization" or "unmarshalling".

Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), you can use annotations (`@JsonProperty`) to identify those Java fields which are parsed from JSON.
Your root object may look like:

```
public class Application {
    @JsonProperty // indicate that this field exists in the JSON structure
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private float count;
    @JsonProperty
    private boolean feasible;
    @JsonProperty("route") // indicates that the field name in the JSON is different from the field name in JAVA
    private Map<Integer, Route> routeMap;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public float getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isFeasible() {
        return feasible;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Route> getRouteMap() {
        return routeMap;
    }
}
```

The class representing the routes may look like:

```
public class Route {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private float arrival;
    @JsonProperty
    private float distance;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public float getArrival() {
        return arrival;
    }

    public float getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
}
```

You can now use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to parse the JSON into Java:

```
// place your JSON in this string 
String json = "{\"id\":\"4T4446Pj\",\"count\":4,...";
// create Jackson JSON <=> Object mapper
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// parse the json into the object
Application parsedObject = objectMapper.readValue(json, Application.class);

System.out.println("id: " + parsedObject.getId());
System.out.println("count: " + parsedObject.getCount());
System.out.println("feasible: " + parsedObject.isFeasible());
System.out.println("Number of routes: " + parsedObject.getRouteMap().size());
System.out.println("Routes:");
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Route> entry : parsedObject.getRouteMap().entrySet()) {
    Integer index = entry.getKey();
    Route route = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println("\tRoute Index: " + index);
    System.out.println("\tName: " + route.getName());
    System.out.println("\tArrival: " + route.getArrival());
    System.out.println("\tDistance: " + route.getDistance());
    System.out.println("\t----------------------------------------------");
}
```

This code will generate the output:

```
id: 4T4446Pj
count: 4.0
feasible: true
Number of routes: 4
Routes:
    Route Index: 0
    Name: The Hague, The Netherlands
    Arrival: 0.0
    Distance: 0.0
    ----------------------------------------------
    Route Index: 1
    Name: The Hague, The Netherlands
    Arrival: 5.0
    Distance: 3.9
    ----------------------------------------------
    Route Index: 2
    Name: Uden, The Netherlands
    Arrival: 93.0
    Distance: 137.1
    ----------------------------------------------
    Route Index: 3
    Name: Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands
    Arrival: 112.0
    Distance: 160.5
    ----------------------------------------------
```

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is not the only library for JSON to Java parsing. But they all share a similar concept.

There are a [lot of annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) beyond `@JsonProperty` to handle issues like ignoring a field, custom parsers or polymorphic type identification.