# Where to find algorithms for standard math functions?

Tags: algorithm, math, reference, d, standard-library

I'm looking to submit a patch to the D programming language standard library that will allow much of std.math to be evaluated at compile time using the compile-time function evaluation facilities of the language.  Compile-time function evaluation has several limitations, the most important ones being:

1. You can't use assembly language.
2. You can't call C code or code for which the source is otherwise unavailable.

Several std.math functions violate these and compile-time versions need to be written.  Where can I get information on good algorithms for computing things such as logarithms, exponents, powers, and trig functions?  I prefer just high level descriptions of algorithms to actual code, for two reasons:

1. To avoid legal ambiguity and the need to make my code look "different enough" from the source to make sure I own the copyright.
2. I want simple, portable algorithms.  I don't care about micro-optimization as long as they're at least asymptotically efficient.

Edit:  D's compile time function evaluation model allows floating point results computed at compile time to differ from those computed at runtime anyhow, so I don't care if my compile-time algorithms don't give **exactly** the same result as the runtime version as long as they aren't less accurate to a practically significant extent.

Answer (score 18):

John Hart *Computer Approximations*  1968 by John Wiley & Sons.

The calculations ideally should match precisely what they would if done at runtime.  That can be tricky. For many functions, no series converges quickly over the full domain, so algoritms paste together various methods.

Also, there are various floating point formats.  Most platforms (I think) now use IEEE 754.  When I wrote a compiler ca. 1985, I had to deal with cross-platform floating point formats. It was very tedious to get it right, because you have to piece the numbers together bit by bit, being sure that you get precisely the value that would be calculated on the target machine.  I don't know if you have to deal with that.

Comment: +1 for the comment that compile-time should match run-time.  Something that compiler writers are too quick to forget.  I'd give it 20 upvotes if I could.  On a less positive note, you mean IEEE-**754**.  488 is a standard for the HP Interface Bus, iirc.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the comment.  IEEE 488 is a different kind of animal entirely.

Answer (score 8):

Jean-Michel Muller's book is an excellent recommendation, as is Hart.

Is it actually necessary for you to own the copyright?  It's usually a bad idea to get into the business of writing math library functions if you can avoid it (and I say that as someone who does so professionally).  I don't know whether or not D can take in BSD-licenced code, but there are several good open-source implementations that may prove helpful.  You may want to look at Sun's [FDLIBM](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/), for example.  Stephen Moshier's [Cephes](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/) would also be a possibility, though its licensing situation is a little bit odd, but I believe that he's been willing to let people redistribute his code under other licenses in the past.

On a side-note, unless you're supporting arbitrary-precision floating-point (I don't think that D does), there isn't usually a notion of "asymptotic efficiency" for libm functions.

Answer (score 5):

As you'd expect, similar issues arise in other languages:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html

> To help ensure portability of Java
>   programs, the definitions of some of
>   the numeric functions in this package
>   require that they produce the same
>   results as certain published
>   algorithms. These algorithms are
>   available from the well-known network
>   library netlib as the package "Freely
>   Distributable Math Library," fdlibm.
>   These algorithms, which are written in
>   the C programming language, are then
>   to be understood as executed with all
>   floating-point operations following
>   the rules of Java floating-point
>   arithmetic.

I don't know what D's rules are for runtime calculation of math functions, but you may be able to pull a similar trick - re-interpret the C source of fdlibm as D. If D calls platform-specific C libraries, then you have the problem that it may be impossible at compile time to predict the runtime value.

I think fdlibm's license is very permissive, you'd have to check for yourself whether it's suitable for redistribution in D. One version I've seen requires a copyright notice to be preserved, and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

The source that I recommend is *Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers* by R. W. Hamming.

This book is published by Dover Press, and is an inexpensive paperback.

Answer (score 3):

See the book ["Elementary Functions: Algorithms and Implementation"](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/SecondEdition.html)
by Jean-Michel Muller.

Comment: hmmm -- looks good about general theory of function approximations. but reading the table of contents, they don't seem to go over specific functions. most functions, if evaluated over a finite range, aren't hard to compute. But over the full range of `double` inputs, exp() and log() and sqrt() aren't trivial to implement. (sin/cos/tan can make use of range reduction) Then you get into erf and gamma and bessel functions and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps you (at least for some of the functions):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Comment: CORDIC isn't appropriate for high-level algorithms, it's more for embedded/digital systems where multiplication is expensive.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say CORDIC is not appropriate. Yes, there may be faster algorithms, if multiplication is cheap (as the wikipedia article points out too). dsimcha asked for "simple" algorithms and doesn't "care about micro-optimization".

Answer (score 2):

several sources, including:

Abramowitz and Stegun, "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" (available [online](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/)!)

Hart, "Computer Approximations" (out of print but good)

also see the several other SO questions about trigonometry, including "[How do Trigonometric Functions Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345085/how-do-trigonometric-functions-work)" and "[Trigonometric Functions on Embedded Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571502/trigonometric-functions-on-embedded-system)".