# How do I find the derivative of sin(x) using recursion?

Tags: c, algorithm

How do I find the derivative of sin(x) where x could be any value e.g. 1,2,3 *using recursion*?

Comment: What makes you think that recursion is a feasible approach to evaluating a trigonometric function?

Comment: Add some clarification in your description. Why do you need to use recursion? Are you not allowed to use the c standard math library functions? Does the answer need to be very precise?

Comment: @Jason, why would it not be feasible? You could write a recursive function to evaluate terms in the taylor series expansion of the cosine, and terminate after reaching a set precision.

Comment: **please at least try** to use full English words. It's a matter of respect for your readers (and no, I'm not a native English speaker, but I do care about the quality of the language we use to communicate with each other).

Comment: I fail to see how this isn't a real question (3 close votes for that), albeit poorly worded but since when did we punish people for not having English as their first language?

Comment: Oh and FYI I think I've demonstrated that recursion is a perfectly viable approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Recursion is not a good choice. I would see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523531/fast-transcendent-trigonometric-functions-for-java

Comment: @Mitch: I think the point is that constraints are given on the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, the derivative of sin(x) is cos(x) or, to put it more formally:

```
f(x) = sin(x)
f'(x) = cos(x)
```

I guess you could solve sin(x) using the [Taylor series for cos(x)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124165821/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53760.html):

```
cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2| + x^2/4! + ...
```

with recursion. In Java:

```
public double cos(double x) {
  return 1 + next(-x*x/2, x, 3);
}

public double next(double term, double x, int i) {
  double next = -term * x * x / (i * (i + 1));
  return term + next(term, x, i + 2);
}
```

Of course you'll need to put some limiter in to exit the recursion otherwise you'll get a stack overflow error eventually, which is left as an exercise for the reader.

Oh and I see the question is tagged as C not Java, but it is homework. :-)

Comment: actually, you very rarely want to evaluate cos(x) using taylor series using the formula you gave. That expansion is around 0, and is generally a good approximation for "small" x (i.e. |x|<1). If you try large x you will quickly notice that since you have only finitely many terms you will break the condition that |cosx|<=1. Usually, you want to use taylor series by expanding around a known easy point close to the actually value that you are looking for.