# Trigonometric functions optimization performance gains in Java

Tags: java, function, optimization, trigonometry

What is the trigonometic functions optimization performance gain over standard methods in Java? Here for example : [Fast transcendent / trigonometric functions for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523531/fast-transcendent-trigonometric-functions-for-java)   I've found some of the methods and libraries to perform similar tasks.

Comment: if you don't understand how it works, it is extremely unlikely that you require these functions.  the built-in functions are likely better documented and maintained.

Comment: @Builder_K I would like first to consider the performance gains so I know if it is even worth to get in depth with this topic at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is also depend on JDK implementation, functions in StrictMath are native.

One of approach is to use some function derived from Taylor series subset.

I remembered the another interesting approach to function calculation. 
Let say you need to have 3d rotating and all arguments are in **limited** integer subset (0..180)/PI.
 So you build precalculated table of values and next use it.

```
double[]result=new double[180];
for(int i=0; i<180; i++) results[i]=Math.sin(i/Math.PI);//end of init
double sin(int value){return result[i];}
```

Comment: Great, but this doesn't answer the question: what were the performance gains?

Comment: gains from which method? You can use CPU sin - performance gain from direct single call to CPU , use another approximation, performance gain from less number of arithmetic operations, use the pre-calculated values, performance gain from direct memory call instead of calculation.

Comment: Elaborate. I guess you have some practical experience doing this, so you can post your observations.